# SSRS Line Chart how displaying Fiscal Month and Year on the Horizontal Axis

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

The sql I used to generate month and year is as below:
left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CLOSED_DT, 112), 6) AS MONTH
The fomat of the Month and year is '201507'. How can I show fiscal year and month on horizontal axis? For example, 'Dec 2015' comes before 'Jan 2016'.

Answer (score 1):

you have created a string, so it will be sorted alphabetically. 
Instead convert to the first day of the month:

DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '2000-01-01', CLOSED_DT), '2000-01-01') as MONTH

That can still be used for grouping, and it will be treated and sorted as a date. 
You can then format the Date as appropriate within the axis